# AspNet Core router added extra URL segment

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have been running into the issue where the AspNet Core router will add an extra segment to the URL when there is an error.

For Example: 
The UseCookieAuthentication will redirect to /login but if there is an error then the router will direct me to /login/login with an error page, and if I continue going to the root URL "http://localhost:59093/" more segments will be added (i.e. http://localhost:59093/login/login)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer on [here](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/issues/354).

It seems that when app.Map is used it rewrites the PathBase with the matching path in app.Map and if there is an error thrown it keeps appending to the PathBase.

This issue does not occur when using app.MapWhen and you get more control so this is how I fixed the issue.

Comment: MapMiddleware did not have a try/catch around the Branch call.  This has been fixed (see [HttpAbstractions issue #510](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/issues/510)) and will be in RC2.  This problem ate my lunch today.